# Show route steps using google API in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps, gps

I am saving latitude and longitude of every 15mins. I need to draw a route with marker of the saved data on google map in codeigniter. Some examples given Start and end points but i need to show my database values on map. Kindly suggest some solutions on this topic.

Controller method:

```
public function geoLocation(){

            $this->load->library('googlemaps');

            $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
            $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
            $config['directions'] = TRUE;
            $config['directionsStart'] = 'Hadapsar, Pune, India';
            //$config['directionsDivID'] = 'swargate, Pune, India';
            $config['directionsEnd'] = 'swargate, Pune, India';

            $config['directionsStart'] = 'swargate, Pune, India';
            //$config['directionsDivID'] = 'swargate, Pune, India';
            $config['directionsEnd'] = 'Bavdhan, Pune, India';

            $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);


            $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

            $this->load->view('google-map', $data);

    }
```

my view:

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
<div id="directionsDiv"></div>
</html>
```

Check above I have three points: Hadapsar, swargate, Bavdhan. I want to draw route on three stations.

Comment: What have you tried so far, could you show some of the code you writen already.

Comment: I have  tried in codeigniter framework(PHP). Take a look on the code and hit good solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using my library. Have you seen waypoints?

https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php#L130

This might be what you're looking for. Only other thing I can think of is, don't use directions, use a polyline:

http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/polyline

Comment: No not a polyline. It wont work for me. I want Starting point, middle step routes and ending point. These all are coming from database and by using these I want to draw direction along with markers.

Comment: This is a borderline link-only answer. You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i want same result i have array of directions i want draw route 
i choose this code

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $config['center'] = 'udaipur, rajasthan, india';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $config['directions'] = TRUE;
    $config['directionsMode'] = "WALKING";
    $config['directionsStart'] = '24.5862087,73.6937057';
    $config['directionsWaypointArray'] = array(
        "24.5866843,73.6890816",
        "24.5878709,73.6878411",
        "24.5900044,73.6896301",
        "24.5973893,73.6857516"
        );
    $config['directionsEnd'] = '24.6045763,73.6853708';
    $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
```